# Firebase crashlytics mapping file upload doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics

I have added firebase crashlytics lib and crashlytics gradle plugin to my project

```
classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0")
...
plugins {
   ...
   id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
   ...
}
...
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0")
```

I explicitly set `mappingFileUploadEnabled` for my release build types with

```
getByName("release").apply {
   firebaseCrashlytics.mappingFileUploadEnabled = true
}
```

But mapping file is unfortunately not uploaded. I verify it in firebase crashlytics console - for my test crashes stacktrace points to `Unknown Source:55`.
Here is what I found in gradle logs:

> [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Mapping File Upload Enabled: false; id: 00000000000000000000000000000000

So it seems my `mappingFileUploadEnabled` flag has no effect. 
Do I need to do something else to make mapping file upload work?

I also don't see `firebaseUpload*ReleaseProguardMapping` tasks in my project. Not sure if it is supposed to be created though.

**UPDATE** 
I have tried to create an empty android project from scratch and added `firebase-crashlytics` there. There it seems to work and I can see `uploadCrashlyticsMappingFile` tasks created for all build types. So for now it looks like `firebase-crashlytics` gradle plugin doesn't work correctly for my project and doesn't create tasks it is supposed to create. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: How did you check it on the Firebase console?

Comment: I didn't check is the mapping file is uploaded(there is probably no way to do that). Instead I checked if the crashes I send were deobfuscated. Assuming that is crashes are deobfuscated then mapping file was uploaded correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learned that if you apply `firebase-crashlytics` gradle plugin declaratively, using the `plugins {}` block the mapping file upload tasks are not created. In order to make it work I had to apply the plugin imperatively using the legacy `apply(..)` function. This is what I have in the project now:

```
apply(plugin = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics")

plugins {
    //other plugins
}
```

After making this change the mapping file upload works fine.

**UPDATE**

I figured out that if I move `crashlytics` plugin to the bottom on my `plugins` section I have the same effect.
Now it looks like:

```
plugins {
    //all other plugins
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}
```